# How to clip the overflowed image bottom of screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I don't have a lot of space left in the bottom of my screen, and I want the image to take as much space as it can, and clip or "ignore" the overflowing part of the image.

I tried so far:
Stack with Overflow.clip and CLip.antiAlias,
BoxDecoration in a Container ( In this solution I don't even see the image),
ClipRect

And There is always an error, that the bottom overflowes by 107 pixels.

Comment: Basically, you want to crop the image. Check this out https://pub.dev/packages/image_crop

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your widgets with SingleChildScrollView

```
Stack(
   overflow: Overflow.clip,
   children:
   [ 
       SingleChildScrollView(
         child: (
           ....
          ),
       ),
   ]
)
```

Comment: I tried the following, but it is still overflowed 



`Stack(
                  overflow: Overflow.clip,
                  children: [
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            image: AssetImage(getIndexedBannerUrl(_bannerToIndex))
                        )),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )`